# Why might an iOS project fail to process a precompiled header for the simulator but work for the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

When I use xcodebuild to build my iOS project for a device, the scheme compiles successfully. When I try to do the same for any iOS simulator, the compilation fails. I've already cleaned and deleted the derived data directories, which didn't help. The two different compilation commands are:

```
xcodebuild -scheme POSShared build
xcodebuild -scheme POSShared -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch),OS=11.2' build
```

I've narrowed down the source of the failure to a *ProcessPCH* step, and the cause is a missing header file, **xpc.h**.

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/itloaner/code/CompanyiOSMPOS/POSShared/POSShared/POSShared-Prefix.pch:14:
While building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:
While building module 'OpenGLES' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:7:
While building module 'IOSurface' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGLIOSurface.h:13:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceBase.h:46:10: fatal error: 'xpc/xpc.h' file not found
#include <xpc/xpc.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

[(Full error output)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JJHrJCnqKaklRo4Qe5hc9jNYfibC3hSTTzvNsvoSI4U)

After isolating the *ProcessPCH* step's LLVM Clang commands, the most obvious differences are:

- -arch x86_64 vs -arch arm7
- -isysroot of iPhoneSimulator.platform vs iPhoneOS.platform
- the exported PATH of the binary directory in iPhoneSimulator.platform vs iPhoneOS.platform

Why would the compilation for the device find **xpc.h** but not find it for the simulator? I've linked to the full *ProcessPCH* commands for the successful and failure compilations to make it possible to diff them and independently verify the minimal differences.

- [Successful commands](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TfkjZX0xbsqOYidpVwc427XArjvXdz-Moy8k-7EjOmY)
- [Failure commands](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qrw5Sl46gsVq-Sv2qNrcpz6Qmbe77HLZ99Gy75C2M-Y)

Comment: You need to also set the SDK to iphonesimulator, otherwise the compiler will try to use the device files while building for simulator. Try adding `-sdk iphonesimulator` to the build command

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Cristik !  Unfortunately, when passing that command line parameter the same error occurs. I've added the full error output.

Comment: Are your build architectures correctly set?

Comment: The successful commands have -arch armv7, the failing ones have -arch x86_64.  I believe that's correct.